# How can I reuse a variable inside a sub query WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the average results of each user.
I Want to find the percentage of users with a better average result.

if you are the fifth user in 20 users, 20% of the users have a better average result.

```
average_results 
+---------+----------------+
| user_id | average_result |
+---------+----------------+
|       1 | 1.0000         |
|       3 | 0.3333         |
+---------+----------------+
```

This is the query I am using. 
When I hardcode the `@user_result` with `0.3333` it works but when I don't it doesn't, as you can see with `position` and `position2`

```sql
SELECT @user_result, position, position2, total, position/total 
FROM 
(
   SELECT @user_result := average_result 
   FROM average_results 
   WHERE user_id = 3  
) as T0,
(
   SELECT COUNT(average_result) as position  
   FROM average_results
   where average_result > @user_result
) AS T1,
(
   SELECT COUNT(average_result) as position2
   FROM average_results
   where average_result > 0.3333
) AS T12,
(
   SELECT COUNT(average_result) as total  
   FROM average_results
) AS T2
```

```
Expected output

+--------------+----------+-----------+-------+----------------+
| @user_result | position | position2 | total | position/total |
+--------------+----------+-----------+-------+----------------+
| 0.3333       |        1 |         1 |     2 | 0.5000         |
+--------------+----------+-----------+-------+----------------+

Actual output

+--------------+----------+-----------+-------+----------------+
| @user_result | position | position2 | total | position/total |
+--------------+----------+-----------+-------+----------------+
| 0.3333       |        0 |         1 |     2 | 0.0000         |
+--------------+----------+-----------+-------+----------------+
```

Comment: What is the reason for wanting it in a variable? Is this part of a larger query?

Comment: You cannot assign & read the same variable in one MySQL select statement & get any particular behaviour. Read the manual re variables & re assignment. PS In code questions please give a [mcve]. PS Read about arithmetic with floats. 0.3333 [sic] is typically not represented exactly in computer systems & my be represented by different values so that exact comparisons in program texts must be done with care.

Comment: @philipxy Thank you for answering the initial question. I am not sure what you would need me to fix. Is the example too minimal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest something like the following, which doesn't answer your actual question about the variable but I think does what you want.

```
SELECT t.*, position/total
FROM
(
 SELECT 
  ar2.average_result as user_result,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ar1.average_result > ar2.average_result THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as position,
  COUNT(*) as total
 FROM average_results ar1 INNER JOIN average_results ar2
  ON ar2.user_id = 3
) t
```

Here is an [sqlfiddle of it working](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5582c/2/0).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *, position / total as 'position / result' 
FROM (
    SELECT 
          MAX( IF(user_id = 3 , average_result, null ) ) as result
        , COUNT(IF( average_result >
            (SELECT  MAX( IF(user_id = 3 , average_result, null ) )
            FROM average_results ), 1,NULL)) as position
        , COUNT( IF( average_result > 0.3333 , 1 , NULL) ) as position2
        , COUNT(average_result) as total
    FROM average_results
    ) as tmp;
```

**sample**